# Let $A^{774}=0$. Show that if $t$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $t=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have tried to tackle the following question and I will like someone check my work.

> Let $A$ be matrix such that $A^{774}=0$. Show that if $t$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $t=0$.

I understand that I need to show two things: existence and uniqueness.

**Existence:** $\displaystyle \det\left(A^{774}\right)=\left[\det(A)\right]^{774}=0\Rightarrow \det(A)=0$. This implies that $A$ is singular, thus $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

**Uniqueness:** Assume there is some $q \ne 0$ which is an eigenvalue of $A$, hence $\det(qI-A)=0$. Substracting $q^{774}I^{774}$ from both sides of the original equation we get $\displaystyle A^{774}-q^{774}I^{774}=-q^{774}I^{774}$, hence $\displaystyle A^{774}-q^{774}I^{774}$ is invertible matrix. Now, $$0\ne \det\left(A^{774}-q^{774}I^{774}\right)=\det\left[(A-qI)(A^{773}+A^{772}qI+...+q^{773}I^{773})\right]=\\=\det(A-qI)\cdot{\det(A^{773}+...+q^{773}I^{773})}=0$$
thus, we got a contradiction $\Rightarrow$ there is no $q \ne 0$ which is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Is my proof valid? is my reasoning fine?

Thanks!

Comment: Theres nothing special about 774 -- any nilpotent matrix only has eigenvalue zero.

Comment: Hint: minimal polynomial.

Comment: Batman, I thought about it, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the second part considerably by observing that if $q>0$ is an eigenvalue, then it has eigenvector $u$, and $0=A^{744}u=q^{744}u$, which is a contradiction since $q,u$ are nonzero numbers,vectors respectively.

Comment: Thanks! yet, is my solution fine?

Comment: it looks fine otherwise.